# How to add different points in multiple lines in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

The sample of my dataset is this:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0no9n.png)

I am quite amateur at this and have written the following code to print the results out with ggplot:

```
mach <- structure(list(n = 1:9, Actual = c(330, 525, 588, 590, 425, 365, 
880, 512, 275.7), ANFIS = c(350L, 500L, 600L, 623L, 423L, 369L, 
876L, 517L, 232L), Fuzzy = c(400L, 575L, 555L, 600L, 400L, 352L, 
856L, 784L, 276L), MLR = c(325L, 600L, 499L, 620L, 389L, 358L, 
877L, 321L, 208L), ANN = c(369L, 360L, 620L, 675L, 477L, 366L, 
652L, 513L, 269L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))


l= c(1,9)
MRR= expression(bold("MRR (mm"^3*"min"^-1*")"))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=mach, aes(x=n, y=Actual, color='Actual')) +
  geom_line(data=mach, aes(x=n, y=ANFIS, color='ANFIS')) +
  geom_line(data=mach, aes(x=n, y=Fuzzy, color='Fuzzy')) +
  geom_line(data=mach, aes(x=n, y=MLR, color='MLR')) +
  geom_line(data=mach, aes(x=n, y=ANN, color='ANN')) +
  geom_point(data = mach, shape=1, aes(x=n, y=Actual)) +
  geom_point(data = mach, shape=2, aes(x=n, y=ANFIS)) +
  geom_point(data = mach, shape=11, aes(x=n, y=Fuzzy)) +
  geom_point(data=mach, shape=4, aes(x=n,y=MLR))+
  geom_point(data = mach, shape=5, aes(x=n, y=ANN))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(.94, .86),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 11, face = 'bold'),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 11, face = 'bold'),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black",
                                        size = 2, linetype = "solid")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(mach$n), max(mach$n), by = 1),1)) +
  labs(y=MRR, x='Number of testing points')
```

The output is this:[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUxkD.png)

I don't have much problem because I only have to present the graph here. But is there any way to shorten my code? It feels quite redundant with many 'geom_line' and 'geom_point'.

Any help would mean a lot!

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(mach)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(mach, 20))`.

Comment: In addition to @RuiBarradas, also [the following reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11374827).

Comment: Hey! @RuiBarradas pardon me for the inconvenience. I have added the data in dput format now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You can reshape your data in order to avoid adding layer by layer. Also next time use `dput()` an do not use screenshots to share data as sometimes it can be complex to copy by hand your data. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Inputs
l= c(1,9)
MRR= expression(bold("MRR (mm"^3*"min"^-1*")"))
#Code
mach %>% pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=n,y=value,color=name,shape=name))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,2,5,11,4))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(.94, .86),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 11, face = 'bold'),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 11, face = 'bold'),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black",
                                        size = 2, linetype = "solid")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(mach$n), max(mach$n), by = 1),1)) +
  labs(y=MRR, x='Number of testing points')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
mach <- structure(list(n = 1:9, Actual = c(330, 525, 588, 590, 425, 365, 
880, 512, 275.7), ANFIS = c(350L, 500L, 600L, 623L, 423L, 369L, 
876L, 517L, 232L), Fuzzy = c(400L, 575L, 555L, 600L, 400L, 352L, 
856L, 784L, 276L), MLR = c(325L, 600L, 499L, 620L, 389L, 358L, 
877L, 321L, 208L), ANN = c(369L, 360L, 620L, 675L, 477L, 366L, 
652L, 513L, 269L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

Comment: Thank you @Duck ! It even added the points in the legend which I was looking to do to. One query, how does pivot_longer(-1) helped here? I am in a bit of oblivion here

Comment: @ShibaprasadBhattacharya Hi dear. The pivot is keeping first column and moving the other columns ar rows so that the plot can be sketched in an easy way!